# Have dial follow pointer

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a site and we're looking to have a knob/dial follow the pointer. So far I have:

http://www.cybercan.co.uk/rockwelllive/

But the whole graphic needs to rotate but not in a linear way (like the example) but in 60 degree 'clicks'. Any idea how to do this or better still could someone give me a quote and a timescale?

Many thanks,
Richard Pain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to snap it to the nearest 6th of a circle:

```
var divisor = 360 / 6;
degrees = Math.floor(degrees / divisor) * divisor;
```

If the red dot doesn't line up with the options, you might need to shift it round a bit with

```
degrees += (divisor/2);
```